# How can I use the built in DI to resolve a Child View's model?

Tags: c#, razor, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm attempting to resolve the dependencies of a child view when calling it from the parent with `@Html.Partial()` like so.

```
@inject IServiceProvider ServiceProvider

//...

<body>
    @Html.RenderPartial("Layouts/Elements/_Header", ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<_HeaderModel>())
</body>

//...
```

Problem is that the Model `_HeaderModel` isn't registered to the DI Container.  So I get the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Client_Portal.Pages.Layouts._HeaderModel' has been registered.
```

But wait, neither are any of my other models and framework resolves their dependencies just fine!  How is ASP.NET Core handling this behind the scenes and how can I do this myself?  Does it add new models as it finds them?  Maybe I'm missing a simple method that lets the framework handle this instead?

Comment: Seems, like its predecessor, asp.net core mvc also uses convention over configuration paradigm.

Comment: *Use view components*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually trying to implement this in what's called the service locator *anti*-pattern. As in this is not something you should be doing. ASP.NET Core provides a way to render partials with a separate and distinct model and/or injected dependencies: it's called view components. The [usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) is pretty basic overall.

First, create a `ViewComponents` directory in your project and add a `HeaderViewComponent.cs` file to that. Inside that, add a class like:

```
public class HeaderViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var model = await GetModelAsync();
        return View(model);
    }

    public Task<HeaderModel> GetModelAsync()
        => return Task.FromResult(new HeaderModel());
}
```

The only required method is `InvokeAsync`. View components are always async. However, since in this example, nothing is actually happening async (just newing up an instance `HeaderModel`, I added a convenience method, `GetModelAsync` that returns the model wrapped in a `Task`, so there's something to `await`. If you were *actually* doing something async, like querying a database to fetch your model, then there's no need to wrap that in a `Task` separately.

With that in place, add a new view to `Views\Shared\Components\Header\Default.cshtml`. By convention the directory is dictated by the class name of the view component, i.e. the view for `HeaderViewComponent` will be looked for in `Components\Header`. Add your existing partial view code here.

Finally, in your layout or wherever else you need to bring in this partial, simply do:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Header")
```

Since view components are just classes, they can be injected like any other class, meaning you can easily access your context or any other registered service you might need, simply by adding a constructor param for it.